# pkgsrc: cannot install multimarkdown

Tags: macos, installation, multimarkdown, pkgsrc

It seems I could not install multimarkdown using pkgsrc:

```
$ sudo pkgin -y install multimarkdown
pkg_summary.xz                                                                                100% 1801KB 360.3KB/s   00:05
calculating dependencies...done.

1 package to install:
  multimarkdown-4.7.1nb2

0 to refresh, 0 to upgrade, 1 to install
0B to download, 425K to install

installing multimarkdown-4.7.1nb2...
pkg_install warnings: 0, errors: 1
pkg_install error log can be found in /var/db/pkgin/pkg_install-err.log

% more /var/db/pkgin/pkg_install-err.log
...
---Jul 27 11:56:13: installing multimarkdown-4.7.1nb2...
pkg_add: Conflicting PLIST with discount-2.2.6: bin/markdown
pkg_add: 1 package addition failed
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says, installing `multimarkdown` conflicts with the already installed package `discount-2.2.6`.
You can fix it by de-installing it:

```
$ sudo pkg_delete discount
```

Sorry that there is no better answer.

Note that `multimarkdown` can also conflict with `mtools`:

```
$ sudo pkg_add ..../All/multimarkdown-4.7.1nb3.tgz 
pkg_add: Conflicting PLIST with mtools-4.0.18: bin/mmd
pkg_add: 1 package addition failed
```